# Rerun activity in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a project in azure data factory v1, in this project I can rerun a single activity in a pipeline using the monitor functionality, but now I want to migrate this project to v2, but in this version I think that I cant't rerun an activity using the monitor panel. 
Is there any way of rerun a single activity of a pipeline in azure data factory V2?

Comment: Right now is possible to rerun a group of activities in a pipeline starting in one of them, take a look at [rerun-activities-inside-your-data-factory-pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rerun-activities-inside-your-data-factory-pipelines/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23719070)

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom activities (Batch Service | Custom), you can rerun all the pipeline or each activity in monitor functionality.

With other kinds of activities for now it's not possible to rerun.